# Entity Framework migrations in VS Code

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, visual-studio-code, entity-framework-core

I apply EF Migrations in Visual Studio, but I could not apply them via VS Code.

***1.*** What is wrong with the following scripts?

```
dotnet ef migrations enable-migrations -ContextTypeName Demo.ApplicationDbContext -MigrationsDirectory:Migrations
dotnet ef migrations Add-Migration -configuration Demo.Migrations.Configuration Migration_Initial
dotnet ef migrations Update-Database -configuration Demo.Migrations.Configuration
```

***2.*** Is there any feature like PM Console in VS Code?

***3.*** Can I also apply these scripts via cmd besides VS Code Treminal or CLI?

Comment: What error messages are you seeing?

Answer (score 0):

In VS Code you can either use the CLI or powershell in the terminal window. The syntax for these commands are slightly different. It looks like you are mixing the powershell syntax and CLI syntax in your samples. For example for adding a migration the CLI syntax is

```
dotnet ef migrations add Migration_Initial --configuration Demo.Migrations.Configuration
```